# JSP Limit the directories of a File Open dialog

Tags: java, html, jsp

I am currently coding a program using the language JSP.  I was wondering if/how you would restrict the directories a File Open dialogue box can browse, for instance:
The default directory is in `C:/userFiles/username/`   I want the user to be able to browse files in that `/username/` directory, or directories within that directory, but not any directories above like `C:/`, or `C:/userFiles`.  I have done some research, and I could not come across an answer.  Is this possible with JSP, HTML, or Java and if so, how would I do it?  I would prefer JSP or HTML.

Additional Info:
The dialogue box would browse files on a remote server, not on the user's computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The File Open dialog is on the **client machine** and is part of the operating system. You cannot change its behaviour.

In order to list files on a SERVER **you would not use a File Open dialog**, you'd be turning the list of files into HTML and serving that to the browser. Since you're the one writing the server-side code, you are ALREADY the one in control over which files make it into that list in the first place.

Saying you'd prefer "JSP or HTML" is a pretty good indicator that you don't fully understand the client-server relationship of the web.